# add or insert to array inside a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have hash named `data` with a key named `checks` which is an array of dates. If the key exists I want to append to the existing array. If the key does not exist I need to add an array with the current date. **Is there an elegant way to do this in ruby?**

This is how I'm doing it right now which seems harder than it should be:

```
if data.has_key?('checks')
  data['checks'] << DateTime.now
else
  data['checks'] = Array.wrap(DateTime.now)
end
```

Comment: Where does the `data` hash come from and why is the `checks` key missing sometimes?

Comment: I have metadata on a model and sometimes it doesn't have certain keys. For example, some models have a check for dupes...but not all.

Comment: Maybe it would be cleaner to initialize the metadata with an empty `checks` array, so you don't need a "type check" in the first place.

Comment: @Stefan that would work for this particular case but as time goes on we keep adding new data to the metadata field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I'd attack it like this:

```
checks = data['checks'] ||= [ ]
checks << DateTime.now
```

If your `data` hash will only ever have array-like values, do this:

```
data = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }
```

Then you don't need to bother with the `||=` thing since assignment will happen automatically.

Comment: You could also combine the first two lines: `(data['checks'] ||= []) << DateTime.now`

Comment: It worth to mention that [`Hash#default_proc=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) might be set at any time, even if one has a hash that came from outside.

Comment: @Stefan I was trying to keep it as uncomplicated as possible, but that's the convention I actually use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's elegant or not, but you could do:

```
data['checks'] = [*data['checks']] << DateTime.now
```

Basically if data['checks'] is `nil` the splat reduces it to `[]` but if it has entries it reduces to an array with those same entries.

**EDIT** Here's another option no one else has mentioned:

```
data['checks'] = (data['checks'] || []) << DateTime.now
```

**EDIT2** Without using the (potentially confusing) splat operator:

```
data['checks'] = Array(data['checks']) << DateTime.now
```

Comment: Wow this is neat.

Comment: If for some reason one wants to abuse splat operator, it still might be done in more readable way: `data['checks'] = [*data['checks'], DateTime.now]`

Answer (score 2):

```
data['checks'] = data.fetch('checks', []) << DateTime.now
```

Hash#fetch takes a key and a value to return if the key is missing. Perhaps a little more elegant than splatting into an array literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
if data.key?('checks')
  data['checks'] << DateTime.now
else 
  data['checks'] = [DateTime.now]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data['checks']= Array.wrap(data['checks']) << DateTime.now
```

But think more elegant way is this:

```
data['checks']= Array.wrap(data['checks']) + [DateTime.now]
```

`Array.wrap` return a blank array or existing array. Plus operator will merge two arrays and assign new array to `data['checks']`

Answer (score 0):

```
if data[:checks]
  data[:checks] << DateTime.now
else
  data[:checks] = [DateTime.now]
end
```

one liner

```
data[:checks] ? data[:checks] << DateTime.now : data[:checks] = [DateTime.now]
```